# Show wide images in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, wideimage

Hi there i am trying to achieve the following look http://demo.qodeinteractive.com/elision/
where they have very wide images going across. My content are is 960px/1024px wide but obviously I want to have my images one end of the screen to the other (very Wide). how can I achieve that in wordpress twenty12 theme or any theme. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can percent-style your image width with CSS to resize together with the container `div`, for example (assuming your container div has CSS class `container`):

```
<style type="text/css">
div.container img {width:100%}
</style>
```

The above code will keep the aspect ratio of the image.

If you do not care about that, you can add also image height to the CSS rule:

```
<style type="text/css">
div.container img {width:100%;height:100%}
</style>
```

This will squash the image to fit your container `div` no matter how you resize your browser window.